# firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() in reactive form reset

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form that creates a document in Firestore. I have added a timestamp in one of the values of the formgroup but when the form is reset and I resend the values in the field of `estado` and `fecha` I get `null`.

Here my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uubb7t

[image]

```
this.forma = fb.group ({
  valorPropiedad: [ 100000, Validators.required ],
  nombre: [ '', Validators.required ],
  email : [ '', [Validators.required, Validators.email] ],
  celular: [ '',  [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(9)] ],
  acepta : [ false, Validators.requiredTrue ],
  fecha: [ firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() ],
  estado: [ false ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with this code, I do not know if it will be the best but it works for me:

```
this.form.resetForm({ 
  fecha: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  estado: false
});
```

check my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uubb7t